# cannot store a function in map in actions on google

Tags: javascript, actions-on-google

I am making an action on google where I am trying tore some values in a map object in `conv.user.storage`.But everytime it gives me an error that:

conv.user.storage.blist.set is not a function(NOTE: blist is the map object which i have created)

I don't know where am I making a mistake can someone please help me.I am entirely new to this.

Comment: Please update your question to show your code.

Comment: Are you referring to the Map object losing the `set` function between webhook calls?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript Maps and Objects are different data structures (both are implemented as hash tables, but they have different methods).

My guess is that you're probably trying one of the following:

```
const blist = new Map();
blist.set('x', true);
conv.user.storage.blist = blist;
```

or

```
const blist = {};
blist.set('x', true);
```

but it's not working, right?

If that's approximately what you've tried, then good news: there's a simple fix.

**conv.user.storage** needs to be an Object, not a Map, and objects don't have a **set** method.

```
const blist = {a: true};
conv.user.storage = { blist };
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you cannot store functions in the conv.user.storage or conv.data objects across function invocations, probably because the conv object is serialized and deserialized between each webhook call